# Is there a Flutter Image file

Tags: flutter

I want to show a widget if there is no image file in flutter. Methods I've tried

```
try {
  AssetImage carImage =
      AssetImage("assets/brands/" + logoFileName + ".png");
  return Image(image: carImage, height: size);
} catch (e) {
  return Icon(
    Icons.no_photography,
    size: size,
  );
}
```

error if file does not exist
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEAzv.png)

Other method

```
 print(await File("assets/brands/" + logoFileName + ".png").exists());
```

always returns false

I tried other methods but it didn't work

Comment: check `ImageErrorWidgetBuilder? errorBuilder,` property of `Image` widget - the docs say: *"A builder function that is called if an error occurs during image loading."*

Comment: I implemented this solution https://ibb.co/k9jHnGm but this is the result https://ibb.co/82VMZk2

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition as follows:

```
 image!=null?Image(image: carImage, height: size):Icon(
    Icons.no_photography,
    size: size,
  )
```

Comment: If the file does not exist, the situation in the screenshot is happening.